# ZF2 read mail content

Tags: zend-framework2, imap

I need to read the content of a mail in a ZF2 project. I'm able to read the header and the contentType, but not the 'body'. The contentType = multipart/alternative. Until now I use thos following code:

```
$params = array('host' => 'myHost', 'user' => 'myUser', 'password' => 'myPwd');
    $mail = new \Zend\Mail\Storage\Imap($params);

    $cntMail = $mail->countMessages();

    for ($i = $cntMail; $i > 0; $i--) { // reverse order 
        $message = $mail->getMessage($i);

        if (stristr($message->subject, '[Ticket#: I' . 411401 . ']')) {
            echo $message->subject . "\n";
            echo $message->contentType;


            if ($message->isMultipart())
                echo 'is multipart';

            // here the body
            echo $mail->getRawContent($i); //throws an error

            exit;
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated, Andrea

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/skysilo/NetBeansProjects/bookingmanagerv4/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Imap.php on line 566

Answer (score 0):

I connected to smartermail and apparently it is not possible with ZF2 to get the content of mails in smartermail...